# Por que o JSON ou o XML não funciona?

Tags: json, xml, golang

Eu tenho esse tipo:

```golang
type S struct {
    a string    `json:"a" xml:"a"`
    b int       `json:"b" xml:"b"`
    c time.Time `json:"c" xml:"c"`
}
```

Mas nem o JSON nem o XML funcionam:

```golang
s := S{a: "Olá", b: 42, c: time.Now()}
jsonTexto, err := json.Marshal(s)
fmt.Printf("json: %s %v\n", jsonTexto, err)
// json: {} <nil>
xmlTexto, err := xml.Marshal(s)
fmt.Printf("xml : %s %v\n", xmlTexto, err)
// xml : <S></S> <nil>
```

Por que?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para codificar ou decodificar dados, os identificadores devem ser **exportados**. Os identificadores exportados começam com uma letra maiúscula:

```golang
type S struct {
    A string    `json:"a" xml:"a"`
    B int       `json:"b" xml:"b"`
    C time.Time `json:"c" xml:"c"`
}

// ...

s := S{A: "Olá", B: 42, C: time.Now()}
jsonTexto, err := json.Marshal(s)
fmt.Printf("json: %s %v\n", jsonTexto, err)
// json: {"a":"Olá","b":42,"c":"2009-11-10T23:00:00Z"} <nil>
xmlTexto, err := xml.Marshal(s)
fmt.Printf("xml : %s %v\n", xmlTexto, err)
// xml : <S><a>Olá</a><b>42</b><c>2009-11-10T23:00:00Z</c></S> <nil>
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/JkQ5gyo9DDx.